# Scale object within confines of cube dimensions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale, gameobject

I have several `gameObjects` of inconsistent sizes and dimensions, and a cube whose transform scale is set to `0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f` in worldspace.

I would like to ensure that all `gameObjects` scale to a consistent size, within the maximum dimensions of the cube.

I have tried parenting the gameObject to the cube, then localscaling to 1,1,1. I have also tried localscaling to the bounds of the cube after parenting. Neither have worked.

How can I ensure consistency in sizing assuming I don't have a standard gameObject size?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will want to leave out scale at 1f, 1f, 1f. To prevent some scaling issues, I suggest that you parent the game objects with 0.1f scale to an empty with 1f scale and work with that.

Comment: Thanks Kyle will try this out and report back.